# mysql - return row where date is equal to some value

Tags: mysql

I have table assessment as given below-

```
SLNO  EID  Period_From   Period_To
 1    101  2017-06-01    2017-11-14
 2    102  2017-07-01    2017-09-30
 3    103  2017-05-01    2017-07-31
```

If  Period_To and currentdate is equal to 75 days then row should return 1 else 0 I used below query-

```
 SELECT SLNO,EID, Period_From,Period_To,(CASE WHEN (PERIOD_TO = (select DATE_ADD(PERIOD_TO,INTERVAL 75 DAY))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ASSESSMENT_ENABLE from assessment;
```

I got result as

```
    SLNO  EID  Period_From   Period_To    ASSESSMENT_ENABLE
     1    101  2017-06-01    2017-11-14    0
     2    102  2017-07-01    2017-09-30    0
     3    103  2017-05-01    2017-07-31    0
```

I am getting wrong result. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you need sub query. try this it works for me

```
SELECT SLNO,EID, Period_From,Period_To,
(CASE WHEN (PERIOD_TO = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d') - INTERVAL 75 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
AS ASSESSMENT_ENABLE
```

Comment: Why are you using `DATE_FORMAT` here?

Comment: you don't have to use it i copy it from my db and i have different format

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using `CURRENT_DATE` and `DATEDIFF` functions:

```
SELECT 
    SLNO, EID, Period_From, Period_To,
    IF(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), date_to) = 75, 1, 0) AS ASSESSMENT_ENABLE
FROM
    ASSESSMENT
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
select
    SLNO,
    EID,
    Period_From,
    Period_To,
    case when (DATEDIFF(now(),PERIOD_TO)=75) then 1 else 0 end as ASSESSMENT_ENABLE
from
    assessment;
```